# Return records with repeating column value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a value in a column and return the rows whose occurrences is greater than one.

For example:

```
SomeId   AnotherId
1        BC4
1        CDE
1        SDF
5        ER
5        WER
4        DFGR4
```

I would like to be able to get the `SomeId` whose occurrence in the column `SomeId` is greater than one.

I have looked at using `SUM` and `GROUP` but no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the Ids that occur more than once.

```
SELECT SomeId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SomeId
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SomeId
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY SomeId
    HAVING COUNT(SomeId) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SomeId, COUNT(SomeId) AS someidcount
FROM tablename
GROUP BY SomeId
HAVING someidcount > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*) as frequency, SomeId group by SomeId having frequency > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with GROUP BY but you also needed HAVING.

Try this:

```
SELECT SomeId, COUNT(SomeId)
FROM table
GROUP BY SomeId
HAVING COUNT(SomeId) > 1
```

Here's a link to [a Wikipedia article on the HAVING clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select SomeId, Count(distinct AnotherId)
  from YourTable
 group by SomeId
having Count(distinct AnotherId) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are familiar with PHP you can do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc):
if($row['SomeId'] > 1):

{do whatever you like here...}

endif;
endwhile;
```

Comment: That's wrong and is anyway a very bad idea. Do not use PHP when you don't need it.

Comment: I am only suggesting this IF the this user was using PHP and the purpose of the database was for PHP. If not then yes, it is a bad idea lol

Comment: First, your solution simply _does not work_. It does not do what OP wants. Second, even if it worked, even if OP used PHP (never a good idea to assume) it would still be a bad solution. You __should not__ use PHP to do a DBMS's job.